# Fragment ToolBar not showing menu buttons

Tags: android

I have a bottomsheet navigation with a toolbar attached to the top, and I am trying to display a play menu button. But instead of showing up on the bottom toolbar, it shows on the main toolbar where the settings menu is.

```
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_coor);



    final View bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

    final BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottomToolBar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

The above code is in the fragment, here are the options menu methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_play, menu);
}
```

Here is the menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_play_bar"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_play_arrow"
        android:title="@string/play_button"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

And this is the xml for the bottom sheet navigation, where I want the toolbar to be displayed:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/bottomToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Play now!"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Any help as to why it's showing up in the main navigation drawer toolbar and not the bottom toolbar would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up things here. That's why you are getting this.

here is a sample code block. put it inside any FrameLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

here `app:menu="@menu/navigation"` should provide the menu to this widget just like `DrawerLayout`. You don't need to explicitly inflate this. Now put your play menu item in this navigation menu and Voila!!

`onCreateOptionsMenu(..)` is used to add menu to the Toolbar

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setHasOptionsMenu(true)
 }
```

You didn't write this overridden method in the fragment.
Hope this Helps!!!